# Failed to fetch - node:internal/errors:477 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);

Tags: mern

I have this code

export const getRoomBySearch = async(req,res)=> {

```
const price = parseInt(req.query.price)

// here 'i' means case sensitive
// const block = new RegExp(req.query.block)
// const maxGroupSize = parseInt(req.query.maxGroupSize)

try {
    
    // gte means greater than equal
    const rooms = await Room.find({
        price: {$gte:price},

        // block,
        // maxGroupSize: {$gte:maxGroupSize},
    })

    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: "Successful",
        data: rooms,
    }).populate('reviews');
} catch (err) {
    res.status(404).json({
        success: false,
        message: "Not Found"
    })
}
```

}

when I tested to search it works but if I want to back on home page it send me the error message Failed to fetch and in the command prompt it shows me this error

```
node:internal/errors:477
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:603:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\khaminah\Desktop\realProjjects\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\khaminah\Desktop\realProjjects\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:275:10)
    at getRoomBySearch (file:///C:/Users/khaminah/Desktop/realProjjects/backend/controllers/roomController.js:159:25)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: The error you are seeing means you are trying to perform an action on data which isn't available at the time you want to do the second action... And I think `..populate('reviews');` is the one which is causing the error you are seeing!